# 301 redirect append string after redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using htaccess file for permanent redirection, but after redirection additional query string appended in url by default.

my htaccess code is

```
Redirect 301 /text/text2 http://www.mysite.com/text/text2-another-text3
```

the result is
    http://www.mysite.com/text/text2-another-text3?/text/text2

i am using codeigniter for my application

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the route part as they are by default controller/function...

Comment: i have checked my route file, i don't know why this is happening if i use htaccess for permanent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file. The`?` at the end will prevent query string parameters from being passed on.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^text/text2$ http://www.mysite.com/text/text2-another-text3? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But problem remains same. i am still getting the query string part